# find path in prolog

Tags: prolog

HI,I HAVE THESE DATA

```
Quote:

flight(Place1,Place2,departure time,Arrival time,flight code,Day)
flight(paris,milano,6,8,ba4733,mo).
flight(milano,london,9,10,ba4733,mo).
flight(london,athens,10,15,ba4733,mo).
flight(milano,paris,10,15,ba4733,mo).
```

i want to find all  paths between 2 places for example

```
?- route(paris,athens,mo,A).

A = [flight(paris,milano,ba4733,8), flight(milano,london,ba4733,10), flight(london,athens,ba4822,15)] ;
```

also to flight from place1 to place2 needs Day1=Day2 and Arrival time<=departure time

I have done these but my program stacks really bad:

```
apeuthias_ptisi(P1,P2):-ptisi(P1,P2,_,_,_,_).
flight(P1,P2,COD,AF):-ptisi(P1,P2,_,AF,COD,_).


antapokrisi(P1,Y,P1):-!.
antapokrisi(P1,Y,P2):-ptisi(P1,Y,AN1,AF1,COD1,DAY1),
ptisi(Y,P2,AN2,AF2,COD2,DAY2), AF1=<AN2, DAY1==DAY2.


path(X,Y,D,L2):-c2(X,Y,[],D,L),reverse(L,L2).

c2(X,X,L,D,L):-!.
c2(X,Y,L,D,L2):-antapokrisi(X,Z,P2),ptisi(X,Z,AN,AF,COD,D),not(member(Z,L)),c2(Z,Y,[flight(X,Z,COD,AF)|L],D,L2).



route(P1,P1,D,R):-!.
route(P1,P2,D,R2):-setof(R,path(P1,P2,D,R),R2).
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Since it's homework, I won't give the full solution, but here're some tips that should be enough:

Essentially, this is the same problem as "is person A an ancestor of person B" which you've probably done already (or seen the solution of as an example). This problem just has a couple more constraints (from your question: "flight from place1 to place2 needs Day1=Day2 and Arrival time<=departure time").

A few useful things:

- `X =< Y` will succeed when `X` is smaller than or equal to `Y`
- Your predicate `route` need to be recursive, with two branches: a base case and a recursive case.
- To find the base case, think about what is the simplest way for there to be a route from A to B.
- From the base case, find the recursive step by finding the smallest way to extend an existing path.

Hopefully this is enough to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use the following for your homework solution; it might be terribly wrong!  It's also written in my (possibly bad) Prolog programming style.  The way I solved this problem is the famous ancestor predicate for family trees:

```
ancestor( X, Y ) :-
    parent( X, Y ).
ancestor( X, Y ) :-
    parent( X, Z ), 
    ancestor( Z, Y ).
```

where parent is defined in the normal way and so are the other predicates it uses.

Are there anymore flight/6 rules you were given?

```
% list of flights
% need more to properly test really
flight( paris, milano, 6, 8, ba4733, mo).
flight( milano, london, 9, 10, ba4733, mo ).
flight( london, athens, 10, 15, ba4733, mo ).
flight( milano, paris, 10, 15, ba4733, mo ).
flight( milano, paris, 17, 15, ba4733, mo ).

% clause to add an intermediate variable
route( Start, End, Day, F ) :-
    route( Start, End, Day, [], F ), !.
% base case
% we use reverse/2 as [Head|List] notation means
% that the list is backwards
route( Start, End, Day, Inter, F ) :-
    flight( Start, End, ST1, ET1, Code1, Day ),
    ET1 >= ST1,
    F1 = [flight( Start, End, ST1, ET1, Code1, Day )|Inter],
    reverse( F1, F ).
% recursive case
% start and end times checked on each recursion so the
% overall start and end time must satisfy our constraint
% of end time >= start time
route( Start, End, Day, Inter, F ) :- 
    flight( Start, Somewhere, ST1, ET1, Code1, Day ),
    ET1 >= ST1,
    route( Somewhere, End, Day, [flight(Start, Somewhere, ST1, ET1, Code1, Day)|Inter], F ).
```